# Should you implement the ViewHolder pattern in an Android Activity?

Tags: android, android-viewholder

Up to now I've been using `ViewHolders` for `RecyclerView`s

I was wondering is it correct to use it for an activity?

What I'm doing up to now is in the `OnCreate` method of an activity I always call a method called `assign_views` which looks something like this:

```
//instance variables
TextView _text_view_1;
TextView _text_view_2;
//etc


void assing_views(boolean assign){
    _text_view_1 = assign ? (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_view_1) : null;
    _text_view_2 = assign ? (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_view_2) : null;
}
```

and in the OnDestroy method of an activity I call `assign_views(false)`

so would there be a benefit in me changing it to something like this:

```
private ActivityViewHolder get_holder(){
    return (ActivityViewHolder)getRootView().getTag();
}


void assign_views(boolean assign) {
   if (assign && get_holder() == null) {
      getRootView().setTag(new ActivityViewHolder());
      get_holder().text_view_1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_view_1);
      get_holder().text_view_2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_view_2);
   } else if (!assign){
     getRootView().setTag(null);
   }
}


static class ActivityViewHolder {
   TextView text_view_1;
   TextView text_view_2;
}
```

and then replace all my references from `_text_view_1` to `get_holder().text_view_1`

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide

Answer (score 0):

`onDestoy()` is called when activity is finishing or going to be re-created, because of screen rotation or other config changes. Probably, some dimensions will change, for example height of `ActionBar` is different for landscape and portrait, or another layout file will be used for new orientation.
If you want to store your view, without re-creation, you can handle screen rotation manually. It is bad practice, and there are not so many cases when you really should use it. Just follow this steps:

1. In your manifest add
   `<activity
       android:name=".MyActivity"
       android:label="@string/title_my_activity"
       android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden" />`
2. Override [`onConfigurationChanged()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onConfigurationChanged(android.content.res.Configuration)) in your activity to handle changes.